# Lag Dataframe in R

Tags: r, lag, sapply

I have the following data.frame:

```
A <- c(10,
       12,
       14.4,
       17.28,
       20.736)
B <- c(6,
       7.8,
       10.14,
       13.182,
       17.1366)

df <- data.frame(A, B)
df
```

Which looks like this:

```
       A       B
1 10.000  6.0000
2 12.000  7.8000
3 14.400 10.1400
4 17.280 13.1820
5 20.736 17.1366
```

Now, I'd like to have the exact table, but with growth factors:

```
   A   B
1  1   1
2  1.2 1.3
3  1.2 1.3
4  1.2 1.3
5  1.2 1.3
```

So the "lag" should be one position: the next value should be divided by the precedent value.
Is there a function for this?

Comment: How do you figure a 1.2 growth on the first row of `A`?

Comment: is that the expected output at the end

Comment: 1.2 = 12/10
1.2 = 14.4/12
1.2 = 17.280/14.4 etc.

Comment: D.Studer, sure, but that's four 1.2 ... where does the fifth come from?

Comment: Sorry, the first values should be 1 (or 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values shouldn't update for the next iteration

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_all(~ ./lag(., default = first(.)))
#   A   B
#1 1.0 1.0
#2 1.2 1.3
#3 1.2 1.3
#4 1.2 1.3
#5 1.2 1.3
```

---

If values needs to be updated, we can use `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
df %>% 
     mutate(A =  purrr::accumulate(A, ~ .x/.y))
```

Or for multiple columns

```
df %>%
        mutate_all(~ purrr::accumulate(., `/`))
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```r
df2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(a) c(1, a[-1] / a[-length(a)])))
df2
#     A   B
# 1 1.0 1.0
# 2 1.2 1.3
# 3 1.2 1.3
# 4 1.2 1.3
# 5 1.2 1.3
```

I'm inferring the first one should be "1.0" since there is no growth on the first. One could also easily argue that the first should be `NA`. Over to you.